# Methods changing the object that calls them vs methods that return a changed object

Tags: javascript

In Javacript, the following `reverse`-call will permanently change the array which calls it:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push(1,2,3);
arr.reverse();
alert(arr); // 3,2,1
```

The same is true for the `sort` method for arrays. On the other hand, some methods do not change the object that calls them. Instead, they return a result of the function call which can be assigned to another variable, should we want to do so. For example, `concat`:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("Hi");
new_arr = arr.concat("again!");
alert(arr); // "Hi"
alert(new_arr); // "Hi","again!"
```

My questions are:

1. What is the reason behind the choice of having some methods perform their operations on the very objects which called them, and some methods only return a result of the operation?
2. What are the respective names for each of these types of methods?

Comment: 1. This can only be answered by people who worked on the spec. Maybe ask Brendan Eich on Twitter.
 2. Such methods are usually called something along the lines of "mutation methods", since the underlaying data structure is "mutated" (objects are *mutable* data structures in JavaScript). Not sure if there is a name for the other.

Comment: immutability is a core concept in functional programming https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0

Comment: @FelixKling The opposite of "mutable" is "immutable" :-) Or rather, *mutating* vs *non-mutating* methods.

Comment: @Bergi: I know that ;) I just wasn't sure if there is a specific name for these methods (other than non-mutating).